# Is sequence of domain names in server_name entry in NGIX configuration file important?

Tags: nginx

I am having different behavior when I change the sequence of domain names in the line:  *server_name example.com custom.example.com;*

Is the sequence important? The forwarding fails when I **change** the sequence.

```
     server { 
       listen   443 ssl http2;
       server_tokens off;
       server_name example.com custom.example.com;
       ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
       location / { 
         # app1 reverse proxy follow
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-RemoteAddr $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://192.168.3.211:12000;
       }   
     }   


     server {
        listen       80 ;
        server_name  example.com custom.example.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri?  permanent;    
        server_tokens off;
      }
```

I get a nginx welcome message when I change the sequence. One cert is used  for the main domain and the subdomains.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  custom.example.com does not get forwarded. I get the Welcome to Nginx message.  There is a single letsencrypt cert for all sub-domains and the main domain.  Disclaimer: Just getting started with Nginx.

Comment: In your example order is irrelevant, it's probably some kind of error. I'd have to try it out to spot it as you haven't given any curl, any errors, etc. There's an excellent reference [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms).

Comment: @Tim Useful link for getting started. Helps.